# MUI Multiple Select with Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik, yup

I would like to make a multiple Select with MUI in my form that is made with Formik, it is my first time using MUI and Formik so I have the question below.
Following the MUI documentation I made the Select like this (I am not sure if the projectSchema and the initialValuesProject are correct.):

```
/*(...)*/

const projectSchema = yup.object().shape({
  usersId: yup.array().of(yup.string()),
});

const initialValuesProject = {
  usersId: [],
};

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250,
    },
  },
};

const Calendar = () => {
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);
  const { data } = useGetAllUsersQuery();

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = event;
    setPersonName(
      // On autofill we get a stringified value.
      typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value
    );
  };

  /*(...)*/

  return (
    /*(...)*/
    <Formik
      onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
      initialValues={initialValuesProject}
      validationSchema={projectSchema}
    >
      {({ values, handleChange, handleSubmit, setFieldValue }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <FormControl size="small" sx={{ m: 1 }}>
            <Select
              id="encargadoP"
              multiple
              value={personName}
              onChange={handleChange}
              MenuProps={MenuProps}
              renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
              sx={{ width: 205 }}
            >
              {data?.map(({ _id, name }) => (
                <MenuItem key={_id} value={name}>
                  <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(name) > -1} />
                  <ListItemText primary={name} />
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default Calendar;
```

This way it works visually but not when Submitting the data.

So I tried to change the value of the Select but that does not show the selected data in the Input, so I would like to know what to put to value and onChange?

I tried this way:

```
<Select
              id="encargadoP"
              multiple
              value={values.usersId}
              onChange={handleChange}
              MenuProps={MenuProps}
              renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
              sx={{ width: 205 }}
            >
              {data?.map(({ _id, name }) => (
                <MenuItem key={_id} value={name}>
                  <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(name) > -1} />
                  <ListItemText primary={name} />
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Select>
```

I am very grateful to those who can help me. <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formik uses `name` to recognize your field, so passing attribute `name="usersId"` in `Select` component may solve the problem.

```
<Select
  id="encargadoP"
  name="usersId"
  multiple
  value={values.usersId}
  onChange={handleChange}
  MenuProps={MenuProps}
  renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
  sx={{ width: 205 }}
>
  /*(...)*/
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Formik expects a field called `name` that should map to one of th keys in the initialValues object. Ideally, for every key in initialValues object, there should be a field against it with its name attribute.

To make the code work, all you got to do is add another attribute in Select Component.

```
<Select
    id="encargadoP"
    name="usersId"
    multiple
    value={values.usersId}
    onChange={handleChange}
    MenuProps={MenuProps}
    renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
    sx={{ width: 205 }}
>
    /*Rest of the code*/
</Select>
```